# Write a method which computes the first twenty Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c#, beginner

It's a task from a C#-course I'm currently taking.
The task is to write a method, which returns the first twenty Fibonacci-numbers.

I have done it the following way.

```
using System;
namespace CrashCourse
{
    public class Fibonacci
    {
        // ... The actual method 
        public static List<int> GetNumbers() {
            var numbs = new List<int> { 1, 1 }; // Provided. Not by myself.

            for (var i = 2; i < 20; i++) {
                var prev2 = numbs[i - 2];
                var prev1 = numbs[i - 1];
                numbs.Add(prev1 + prev2);
            }

            return numbs;
        }
    }
}


// Usage
var numbs = Fibonacci.GetNumbers();
foreach(var numb in numbs) {
    Console.WriteLine(numb);
}
```

What's your opinion about my coding concerning naming, style and algorithm?

What should I do differently and why?

Comment: Stretch your knowledge of C# and look at [iterator methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), specifically [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to CR.

**The Good:** Your indentation and spacing is decent enough.  You separate the tasks of gathering the numbers and displaying the numbers into 2 different methods.

**The Bad:** The first comment `// ... The actual method`  is utterly useless.  The method `GetNumbers()` would be better suited to be named `GetFirst20Numbers()` as it is hardcoded to do just that.

In C#, the convention is to put the opening brace on a new line.

While your solution, most likely for homework or training, is very specific, I would suggest it is **too** specific.  The more flexible and reusable solution would be to create a method that produces Fibonacci numbers, and let a calling method determine how many that should be.  This could be done 1 of 2 ways: one would be to pass in an integer of the desired count, e.g. `GetNumbers(20)`.  The other would be to use an enumeration to produce the next Fibonacci number in a sequence.  Each subsequent call would return 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

> What's your opinion about my coding concerning naming, style and algorithm?

**algorithm**

First twenty [Fibonacci numbers](https://oeis.org/A000045) commonly begin with 0,1,1..., not 1,1,2...

Perhaps OP is stuck with `{ 1, 1 }`.  A comment like "Provided. Not by myself." alone does not excuse this non-convention.

Code to your *contract* requirements, yet when they differ from convention, note it.